# React activeClassName is not working on server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

React activeClassName="active" is not working on server. It is working properly on my local.

**Navbar.js**

```
<ul className="sidebar-elements">
    <li><NavLink to="/" exact activeClassName="active">Dashboard</NavLink></li>
    <li><NavLink exact to="/about" activeClassName="active">About Us</NavLink></li>
    <li><NavLink exact to="/contact" activeClassName="active">Contact Us</NavLink></li>
</ul>
```

**Routes.js**

```
<Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
</Switch>
```

**App.js**

```
<div className ="App ">
    <div className="contentSection">
        <Navbar/>
        <main id="content">
            <Routes /> 
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(<Router><App /></Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Output on My Local

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRHzL.png)

Output on server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1EkU.png)

Comment: "Is not working" is not going to help answer your problem. Please describe the intended output(output on local machine) and the difference on your server.

Comment: What is the version of react router?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",

Comment: Did you push your css file(s) when you pushed your code to your server ? If the class `active` is never listed in a pushed css file, what happened is totally normal

Comment: css file is already there.  on server HTML is like <a href="/">Dashboard</a> and on local <a aria-current="page" class="active" href="/">Dashboard</a>

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be if your application is served as a sub-directory on your production like http://yourdomain.com/your-application.
In this case you should use Router's [basename](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) property.